# When the output power of an amplifier significantly varies despite having a load of much higher impedance than the source impedance

Tags: impedance, headphones

I was looking at headphone amplifiers, and you hear the same thing repeated over and over "at most source impedance is 1/8th the load". The point is to make sure the headphones have a flat frequency response despite it having a variation in impedance, resulting in uneven power at different frequencies. The reason being told that an amplifier yields different power for different loads. This makes sense when looking at the standard equation for an amplifier. You want it to be load impedance dominated to reduce the change in power with impedance.

But when you look at the power output measured from different headphone amps (https://youtu.be/xLShpyzwvJs?t=88) they still seem to vary in power output despite some even having near zero impedance. This seems to mean that headphones might have significant frequency changes on these amps despite the rule.

What is going on here, or am I interpreting the results incorrectly?

Comment: Look at the MOTU M2 for example, its output power goes up @ 150 ohms, then proceeds on the normal trend of slowly going down. Yet, it has near zero impedance.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is going on here, or am I interpreting the results incorrectly?*

The measurement of power and the value produced depends on two things; the voltage signal level supplied and, the impedance of the load. Any electro-acoustic interface will have a complicated impedance versus frequency so, despite the amplifier's best intent at keeping the signal level constant at such and such a frequency, power level into the headphones will inevitably show a range of values across a range of frequencies.

And, of course, if a higher headphone impedance is used, the power will also be proportionately lower for the same signal level from the amplifier because the apparent power level equals signal-level-squared divided by headphone impedance.

Some amplifiers may also choose to compensate for the headphone impedance and, these will appear to produce a more constant power output when different headphones are used. But, is this really such a big deal. I mean. how often will you be swapping one headphone set with another to make comparisons and, if you did, wouldn't you just turn up the volume a little.

Some of these audiophile comparison tables paint a really daft picture of reality so don't get drawn into a battle of trivialities and pointlessness. A commonly used term for audiophiles (on this site and others) is audiofools.

Comment: Quite so - audio amps typically aim to provide a consistent voltage gain irrespective of load impedance, so if the load impedance changes significantly with frequency then the power delivered will vary.  Furthermore the transmitted power into the air is not guaranteed to be constant across the frequency range for any given transducer.

Comment: I'm not an audiophile nor do I care about anti-audiophile activism. Anyway, I was discussing why amplifiers have different power characteristics despite near zero impedance, and the gentlemen pointed out that transistor based amplifiers have an output current which is a function of the base current and the load impedance (load line). As a result, if the base current is high enough, the characteristic curve for varying impedance may have a maxima that is not the same as the source impedance of the amplifier. This is what prompted me to question the idea of only focusing on source impedance.

Comment: @Goschie modern amplifiers will use a thing called negative feedback. Negative feedback totally allows an amplifier to have near-zero output impedance and, the concept of a load line (used in simple class A amplifiers) has no more useful meaning. You can, without risk of over-simplification, regard a modern audio power amp as having near-zero output impedance. This does not mean they produce the same power output for a different load impedance just as the same power is not taken from an ideal battery with different value load resistors.

Comment: @Andyaka I understand that they don't have the same power output at different load impedances. But the entire point of wanting something to be load impedance dominated is to reduce how much the power fluctuates over as large an interval of impedances as possible. But when I look at the measurements people take of modern amps, they don't necessarily do that. It makes me think either there is something wrong with some of these peoples measurements or the importance of source impedance might be partially a myth (at least with modern amps)

Comment: @Andyaka If Bob has a headphone which has an impedance that varies substantially with frequency, and then Alice has two amplifiers, one that has a stable output over a range of loads and one that has an unstable output. Would it not be beneficial to Bob to plug it into the more stable amp, so the frequency deviates less? Especially if the deviations translate to greater than 3 decibel changes, and Bob needs them to be that accurate? Or am I supposed to say it does not matter because in your opinion that would be less of an audiophile thing to do?

Comment: From what I understand, amplifiers that are capable of determining the load impedance and making a gain correction, make this judgement using a small DC current. This can establish (broadly speaking) the nominal impedance of the headphones. E.g. for an 8 ohm speaker, the DC resistance will be around 6 ohm and, of course, a higher impedance speaker will have a proportionately higher DC resistance. This doesn't mean that an amplifier will recognize the instantaneous speaker impedance and correspondingly adjust its gain <-- that is far too complex and I've never come across one that does.

Comment: Even if an amplifier *could* make this work, there are no guarantees that the impedance measured directly corresponds with sound-pressure output at that frequency. So, no, this doesn't work or make sense.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm pretty sure the engineers who design headphones rather make them have a flat impedance response to frequency. If they don't, they will vary too much with the amp, meaning professionals who rely on consistency will have a more difficult time. Unfortunately, some headphones do not, and there have been measurements on them revealing changes in response as much as 6db. Thats definitely in the human hearing threshold. I'm a physicist, not an engineer, but i'm pretty sure an engineer would want a consistent product for audio engineers and the like.

Comment: @Goschie my point is that an amplifier will not try to dynamically compensate (on the fly) for variations in speaker impedance across the audio spectrum.

Comment: @Andyaka Is a stable amplifier not supposed to have a power output that is inversely proportional to impedance? When you look at a graph of that function, its second order derivative is continuously decreasing in magnitude, meaning higher load impedances have a higher tolerances for changes in impedance. Thats basically what I meant by stability.

Comment: A power amplifier (in audio terms) delivers a voltage waveform that is an amplified version of the input waveform irrespective of the load impedances attached to its output (within reason of course).

Comment: @Andyaka So it seems more and more like having near zero source impedance is no guarantee that an amp will not be strongly affected by load impedance when it comes to its amplitude of output. The RMS power of the output signal can still be well affected over small load impedance intervals in some amps, despite the near zero source impedance.

Comment: No, an amplifier with near-zero output impedance produces a voltage output that is **largely unaffected** by load impedance. That is what I have been saying all along this conversation and in my answer. There is no such meaningful quantity in engineering as **RMS power**.  A power level in engineering is the average of volts multiplied by current (aka average power).

Comment: @Goschie if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: No offense, but something feels really off about what you are saying. I'm not an expert, but you are stating things that are obviously untrue. There IS a difference between RMS power and peak power. Peak power for instance is the energy/second that can only be sustained for a short period of time, while RMS is the average power that can be continuously sustained.

Comment: When you look at the power output of an amplifier under loads, the only variation in output you should see should depend on the load impedance. You do a simple voltage divider calculation utilizing the amplified voltage and the load impedance. The amplified voltage SHOULD stay the same. We are in agreement here, have been the entire time. What I am trying to explain is when you look at the power measurements from amplifiers, they DO NOT reflect that. In a non-existent perfect amplifier, you should see the output peak when the load matches the source impedance, then slowly go down. It does not.

Comment: @Goschie read this and note that extended discussions in comments are not allowed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_power#Continuous_power_and_.22RMS_power.22

Comment: @Goschie It would be best to drop the conversation at this point, no use arguing.